# Hadoop 2.7.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 and Eclipse Local Run: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop, noclassdeffounderror

I recently started learning how to setup Hadoop and have written my first application by following Hadoop: The Definitive Guide book. However, I am stuck on a step where I have to run my application locally on a small piece of data.

```
mvn compile

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=~/workspace/hadoop-book-mr-dev/target/classes/com/hadoopbook/hadoop_book_mr_dev/

hadoop MaxTemperatureDriver -conf conf/hadoop-local.xml input/ncdc/micro output
```

I ran the commands above in the command line and exported the Eclipse workspace which contains the required classes as my `$HADOOP_CLASSPATH`. The last command which uses my application to analyze the data does not succeed and gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: MaxTemperatureDriver (wrong name: com/hadoopbook/hadoop_book_mr_dev/MaxTemperatureDriver)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I have tried different folders and directories as my classpath but to no avail. Additionally, I read other similar topics and did `Clean->Clean Selected Projects` as well as removing the source folder from my buildpath and then add it back again but none of them are working for me.

Finally, I have also checked that I have `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar` and `hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.1.jar` as buildpath in my Eclipse. I am not sure what else to try at the moment and would appreciate it if anybody could guide me through this step by step.

Here are some additional information to help in debugging the problem. The `pom.xml` that the mvn eclipse step builds from:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.hadoopbook</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-book-mr-dev</artifactId>
  <version>4.0</version>


  <name>hadoop-book-mr-dev</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <hadoop.version>2.7.1</hadoop.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Hadoop main client artifact -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>

    </dependency>

    <!-- Unit test artifact -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hadoop test artifact for running mini clusters -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-minicluster</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>hadoop-examples</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugins</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

The Driver class that the hadoop command tries to run:

```
package com.hadoopbook.hadoop_book_mr_dev;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class MaxTemperatureDriver extends Configured implements Tool {
    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if(args.length != 2){
        System.err.printf("Usage: $s [generic options] <input> <output> \n",
                getClass().getSimpleName());
        ToolRunner.printGenericCommandUsage(System.err);
        return -1;

        }


    Job job = new Job(getConf(), "Max temperature");
    job.setJarByClass(getClass());

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job,  new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.setMapperClass(MaxTemperatureMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(MaxTemperatureReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MaxTemperatureReducer.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new MaxTemperatureDriver(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);

    }
}
```

The list of JARs and Maven Dependencies in my build path:

```
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-client/2.7.1/hadoop-client-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.7.1/hadoop-common-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.1.1/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/xmlenc/xmlenc/0.52/xmlenc-0.52.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/commons-net/commons-net/3.1/commons-net-3.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/jsp/jsp-api/2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-core/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.10/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.10/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro/1.7.4/avro-1.7.4.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.3/paranamer-2.3.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.0.4.1/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.2.4/gson-2.2.4.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-auth/2.7.1/hadoop-auth-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2.5/httpclient-4.2.5.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/server/apacheds-kerberos-codec/2.0.0-M15/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/server/apacheds-i18n/2.0.0-M15/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/api/api-asn1-api/1.0.0-M20/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/directory/api/api-util/1.0.0-M20/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-framework/2.7.1/curator-framework-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-client/2.7.1/curator-client-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/curator/curator-recipes/2.7.1/curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.0/jsr305-3.0.0.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/htrace/htrace-core/3.1.0-incubating/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.6/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.4.1/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.0/xz-1.0.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.7.1/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-util/6.1.26/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-all/4.0.23.Final/netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.9.1/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.3.04/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/fusesource/leveldbjni/leveldbjni-all/1.8/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app/2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common/2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-client/2.7.1/hadoop-yarn-client-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle/2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/2.7.1/hadoop-yarn-api-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-common/2.7.1/hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.2/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/javax/xml/stream/stax-api/1.0-2/stax-api-1.0-2.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-client/1.9/jersey-client-1.9.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.9.13/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-xc/1.9.13/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient/2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-annotations/2.7.1/hadoop-annotations-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/mrunit/mrunit/1.1.0/mrunit-1.1.0-hadoop2.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/mockito/mockito-core/1.9.5/mockito-core-1.9.5.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.1/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/objenesis/objenesis/1.0/objenesis-1.0.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/11.0.2/guava-11.0.2.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/powermock/powermock-core/1.5.1/powermock-core-1.5.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/powermock/powermock-reflect/1.5.1/powermock-reflect-1.5.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.0-GA/javassist-3.18.0-GA.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.5.1/powermock-api-mockito-1.5.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/powermock/powermock-api-support/1.5.1/powermock-api-support-1.5.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/powermock/powermock-module-junit4/1.5.1/powermock-module-junit4-1.5.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/powermock/powermock-module-junit4-common/1.5.1/powermock-module-junit4-common-1.5.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-minicluster/2.7.1/hadoop-minicluster-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.7.1/hadoop-common-2.7.1-tests.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.26/jetty-6.1.26.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.9/jersey-core-1.9.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-json/1.9/jersey-json-1.9.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jettison/jettison/1.1/jettison-1.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.9/jersey-server-1.9.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/net/java/dev/jets3t/jets3t/0.9.0/jets3t-0.9.0.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1.2/httpcore-4.1.2.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/jamesmurty/utils/java-xmlbuilder/0.4/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.42/jsch-0.1.42.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.7.1/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.1-tests.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/commons-daemon/commons-daemon/1.0.13/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-tests/2.7.1/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.7.1-tests.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-common/2.7.1/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/2.7.1/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/3.0/guice-3.0.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey/contribs/jersey-guice/1.9/jersey-guice-1.9.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager/2.7.1/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice/2.7.1/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy/2.7.1/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.7.1.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.6/zookeeper-3.4.6-tests.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient/2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.1-tests.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/extensions/guice-servlet/3.0/guice-servlet-3.0.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty/3.6.2.Final/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar
/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs/2.7.1/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.7.1.jar
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: probably there is some path variables not present in .bashrc file under your home path.